# JSON to XML conversion in the browser using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to convert XML to JSON and JSON to XML. My XML to JSON is successfully done but I am not getting JSON to XML in browser.

I tested my REST application in postman where it shows correctly but I am not getting the result in browser.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#xmltoJson").click(function() {
      var req123 = $("#requesttext").val();
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:8080/BookStore/rest/book/xmltoJson",
        data: req123,
        contentType: "application/xml"
      }).done(function(msg) {
        alert(msg)
        $("#responsebox").html(JSON.stringify(msg));
      });
    });



    $("#jsontoXml").click(function() {
      var req123 = $("#requesttext").val();
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:8080/BookStore/rest/book/JsontoXml",
        data: req123,
        contentType: "application/json"
      }).done(function(msg) {
        alert(msg)
        $("#responsebox").append(msg).html();
      });
    });
  });
</script>



<h1>XML To JSON Converter</h1>
<table class='toptable' border='1'>
  <tr>
    <td id="requestbox">
      <p>XML</p>
      <textarea id='requesttext'></textarea>

    </td>
    <td id='responsebox'>
      <p>JSON</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" value="xmltoJson" id="xmltoJson" />

<input type="button" value="jsontoXml" id="jsontoXml" />





<style>
  h1 {
    color: green;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .toptable {
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    height: 500px;
  }
  #requestbox {
    width: 50%;
    color: blue;
  }
  #responsebox {
    width: 50%;
    color: blue;
  }
  #requesttext {
    width: 100%;
    color: blue;
  }
  #submitbutton {
    width: 100%;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Why don't you provide your REST calls?

Comment: @POST
 @Path("/JsontoXml")
 @Produces("application/xml")
 @Consumes("application/json")
 public String jsontoXsonConverter(String xml){ 
   System.out.println(xml);
  JSONObject json = new JSONObject(xml);
   String json1 = XML.toString(json);
        
  return json1;

Comment: Edit the question, don't add details of code in comments

Comment: What does "msg" look like in the "done" function of the JsonToXML? Is it empty, or some kind of string? It would be useful to know if it's an incorrect result being returned, or you're just not displaying it properly. In other words, does "msg" contain valid XML or not?

Comment: msg is an XML object. Getting valid response when tried using postman but not able to display on html page.

Comment: Try specifying `dataType: "xml"` in the ajax call to ensure you definitely receive an XML document object back.

Comment: @RakeshSharma227 Have you solved your problem?